# Verify if an element satisfies two conditions in the same column

Tags: sql

:)

I have the following situation

[image]

I need a query that is made like this:

- Column 1: all the cod_azienda for which cod_azienda_gerarchia=P2_04 (it means that the cod_azienda is part of hierarchy P2_04)
- Column 2: a column which will tell me if the cod_azienda of the previous column ALSO has cod_azienda_gerarchia=P2_03 (using 'Yes' if so, 'No' if not). If 'Yes', it means that cod_azienda is part of hierarchy P2_04 AND P2_03 hierarchies, if 'No' the cod_azienda is part of P2_04 hierarchy only.

For example:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| P2_CN_JV_001 | Yes |
| P2_CN_MOCE_001 | No |

Because P2_CN_JV_001 both has cod_azienda_gerarchia=p2_04 and p2_03;
P2_CN_MOCE_001, instead, has only cod_azienda_gerarchia=p2_04 and p2_03.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Column 2: a column which will tell me if the cod_azienda of the previous column ALSO has cod_azienda_gerarchia=P2_03` - do you mean the previous **row**?  If so, how do you define previous?  Also, please don't use images, post your sample data in a table.

Comment: Please do not tag multiple RDBMS as they all have different syntaxes. Only tag the one that you are actually using. I have removed all the extra tags and you can [edit] your question to put the one you are using back.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by using a self-join like so:

```
SELECT
    t1.cod_azienda AS [Column 1]
    ,CASE WHEN t2.cod_azienda IS NULL
        THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS [Column 2]
FROM YourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN YourTable AS t2
ON t2.cod_azienda = t1.cod_azienda
AND t2.cod_azienda_gerarchia = 'P2_03'
WHERE t1.cod_azienda_gerarchia = 'P2_04'
```

This should get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Cristina another solution to your problem is by using window function LAG which bring the previous value and the exists operator.

I hope you can use both in your RDBMS.
If something is unclear please let me know and i will clearify.

```
SELECT [Column 1], [Column 2] FROM
 (
SELECT t1.cod_azienda AS [Column 1], cod_azienda_gerarchia
, CASE WHEN 
LAG(CASE WHEN cod_azienda_gerarchia='P2_03' THEN cod_azienda_gerarchia END ) 
 OVER(ORDER BY cod_azienda) IS NULL 
THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' 
END AS [Column 2]
FROM your_table AS t1
)T1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE t1.[Column 1]=cod_azienda
and T1.cod_azienda_gerarchia='P2_04')
```

I hope it helps